# Issues with Instagram Graph API (Insights endpoint)

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-graph-api

Trying to get Instagram insights data through the Facebook API, and keep getting the same error message. I have all the necessary permissions required, auth tokens, etc, and nothing seems to change the response. Any ideas? Here's what I get back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (insights) on node type (InstagramUser)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "A7sn36A6aleX86dUNqQa3kx"
  }
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you using the Instagram Graph API, or the Instagram Basic Display API? The latter doesn't provide any insights.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.